# Xamarin Header won't reach the end

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created this header and now I am struggling with something. In the header I want to add a logo on the left, the title image next to it and on the right I want to add an image. But when I want to add the image on the right, it just gets placed next to the title image. Here is the code:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="#212121" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Source="Logo.png" HeightRequest="30" />
    <Image HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="Title_Dark.png" HeightRequest="30" />
    <Image HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="Nav_Menu_Dark.png" HeightRequest="30" />
</StackLayout>
```

I used the line `HorizontalOptions="End"`, but that doesn't seem to do the trick!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"`, or try using a `Grid`

Comment: you need to be sure the `StackLayout` is filling the horizontal space

Comment: Yeah, I've got what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grid, this code will work fine but you should add some columndefinition if you want more responsive.

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="#212121" HeightRequest="50">
    <Image HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Source="Logo.png" HeightRequest="30" />
    <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="Title_Dark.png" HeightRequest="30" />
    <Image HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="Nav_Menu_Dark.png" HeightRequest="30" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" for the outer stacklayout and then set HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" to the third image. Try this:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="#212121" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
<Image HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Source="Logo.png" HeightRequest="30" />
<Image HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="Title_Dark.png" HeightRequest="30" />
<Image HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="Nav_Menu_Dark.png" HeightRequest="30" />
```